# Django: correct URL appears in developer tools but link doesn't use that src

Tags: django, url, django-templates

I've created a link in a Django template which appears to lead to the correct URL in the elements pane of the developer tools. But the actual link in the page only goes to localhost. I thought I understood how the Django url template tag worked, but I must be missing something.

URL pattern:

```
url(r'^dollhouse/(?P<dollhouse>[0-9]+)$', views.dollhouse, name='dollhouse')
```

Template:

```
{% for workingdollhouse in dollhouses %}
<a href src="{% url 'dollhouse' dollhouse=workingdollhouse.id %}">{{workingdollhouse.dollhouse_name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Text of element appearing in developer console (hovering over the '"/dollhouse/1"' reveals the intended address of localhost/dollhouse/1):

```
'<a href src="/dollhouse/1">dollhouse1</a>'
```

Actual link just goes to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Django.

`a` elements don't have a `src` attribute. The destination goes in the `href` attribute, which you left blank.

```
<a href="{% url 'dollhouse' dollhouse=workingdollhouse.id %}">{{workingdollhouse.dollhouse_name}}</a>
```

Comment: Ah! I figured it was something like that and I just couldn't see it. Thank you.